# Dynamic memory allocation for two dimensional array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was reading a C++ book and the author had mentioned

> two dimensional array can be created using a single new statement.
>
> array_ptr = new int[3][2];

I tried writing a code segment with a single new operator for creating a two dimensional array and it threw compilation errors.

In this case, I felt that the author is wrong.

**Specs**

- In C++ --> new int[10] is allowed

**BUT**

- new int[10][20] is not allowed

Would appreciate some input as if my above conclusions are correct.

Comment: Could you show us the exact code you tried?

Comment: What have you tried exactly? What were your compiler errors? What **C++** book does recommend using `new int[][]`?

Comment: Dynamic allocation via `new` expressions can be used with any instantiable type. Including matrices. So you're wrong.

Comment: See [the SO C++ documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/3017/arrays/10246/a-dynamic-size-matrix-using-stdvector-for-storage#t=201608250443044846244) for a simple matrix class.

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed but you probably got the type of the left hand side wrong. Use:

```
int (*ptr)[2] = new int[3][2];
```

or

```
auto *ptr = new int[3][2];
```

All dimensions other than the innermost must be known at compile-time. If both dimensions are not known at compile-time then you cannot use this sort of syntax. Instead you would use a 1-dimensional array and compute offsets into it to simulate a 2-dimensional array.

NB. In most cases don't use `new` at all, use containers that manage their own memory.

For further ideas about multidimensional arrays, see the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new?rq=1).

Comment: Can elaborate a bit more.
ptr is a pointer to array of 2 integers right?
and what does auto do?

Comment: @KeerthiRanganath edited my answer to include a link to another question with more info

Comment: Yes my left hand side was wrong.

I used int **ptr = int [3][2];

Comment: @KeerthiRanganath auto is a C++11 extension that gets it's type from the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

This function can dynamically create contigious multidimensional arrays.

```
void* ArrayND(size_t size_m, unsigned short numargs, ...);
```

Arguments:

size_m : size in bytes of a single member.

numargs : number of the total dimensions.

... : rows and columns.

Example:

```
int ****arr = (int***)ArrayND(sizeof(int), 4, 3, 2, 5, 20);
arr[0][1][0][11] = 0;
```

Function code:

```
static void* ArrayND(size_t size_m, unsigned short numargs, ...)
{
    va_list listPointer;
    va_start(listPointer, numargs);

    if (numargs < 1 || size_m < 1) return 0;

    size_t* args = (size_t*)listPointer;

    if (!args[0] || !args[numargs - 1]) ///Dimension == 0 case
    {
        va_end(listPointer);
        return 0;
    }

    if (numargs == 1)
    {
        void* array = (void*)malloc(size_m * args[0]);
        va_end(listPointer);
        return array;
    }

    size_t* PtrProdSum = (size_t*)malloc(((numargs - 1) * 2) * sizeof(size_t));
    size_t* PtrProd = &PtrProdSum[numargs - 1];

    if (!PtrProdSum) return 0;

    PtrProdSum[0] = args[0];
    PtrProd[0] = args[0];

    for (unsigned short j = 1; j < numargs - 1; j++)      ///Calculating the number of (*) pointers and double pointers (**)
    {
        if (args[j] < 1)    ///Dimension < 1 case
        {
            free(PtrProdSum);
            free(PtrProd);
            va_end(listPointer);
            return 0;
        }
        PtrProd[j] = PtrProd[j - 1] * args[j];
        PtrProdSum[j] = PtrProd[j] + PtrProdSum[j - 1];
    }

    size_t len = (sizeof(void*) * PtrProdSum[numargs - 2]) + (size_m * PtrProd[numargs - 2] * args[numargs - 1]);
    void** array = (void**)malloc(len);      ///assign a big block of memory

    if (!array) return 0;

    unsigned short j = 0;       ///j = number block of usable memory

    size_t PPprodSum, PprodSum = PtrProdSum[numargs - 2];
    size_t ColMemory = size_m * args[numargs - 1];
    char* ptr = (char*)(array + PprodSum);

    ///assigning array addresses
    if (numargs > 2)
    {
        unsigned short k = 1;       ///k = index of args to process the addresses
        PPprodSum = PtrProdSum[numargs - 3];
        size_t last_jump = args[0];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < PPprodSum; i++)      ///assigning (**) double pointers addresses
        {
            array[i] = (void**)array + (last_jump + i);
            //printf("array[%d]  :  %d  to  %d   last_jump = %d   PtrProdSum = %d   args = %d\n", i, &array[i], array[i], last_jump, PtrProdSum[k], args[k]);

            if (i >= PtrProdSum[k - 1] && k < numargs - 2) k++;
            last_jump += args[k] - 1;
        }
    }
    else PPprodSum = 0;

    va_end(listPointer);
    free(PtrProdSum);

    for (size_t i = PPprodSum; i < PprodSum; i++)       ///assigning (*) pointers to members memory addresses
    {
        array[i] = ptr + ColMemory * j;
        //printf("array[%d] = %d    jump = %d    sum = %d\n", i, &array[i], ptr + (ColMemory * j), (ColMemory * j));

        j++;
    }

    return (void*)array;
}
```

TODO:
Error handling when malloc() fails.

Source from: https://github.com/TheViper01/MyProjects